# Cloning a repo contents and disconnect it from updates

Tags: git

All,

I need a little help/clarification on some cloning.

Basically, I'm wondering how (if possible) to clone a repo and use the contents of that as a starting point for my own repo.

Example.

I have a new git repo for my own project. I want to use Initializr to give me a basic skeleton utilizing bootstrap and all that stuff. However, once cloned, I don't want to track it anymore.

I looked into submodules, but if I understand correctly, you don't modify those files in the parent repo, which is exactly what I would want to do.

Eventually I want to look into creating a project skeleton with our own modules that will get the latest version of initializr or anything else we throw in there.

Comment: AFAICT you just want to remove the remote, no?

Comment: I think so. I also want to be able to modify it. So if I clone those files into my own repo, I want to remove the remote - which I think I can do just by deleting the remote (sourcetree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the origin remote (and remote tracking branches) by running

```
git remote remove origin
```